# Updating an Object based on the Previous one contained in a List, and replacing the Previous one with a New one

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a list of objects. Each object has few integer fields (`id` and some values: `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, `value4`).

`id` property is unique. There's only one object having a particular `id` in the list.

Each time I create a *new object* which has the same `id` as an existing object, I want to add each *value property* of the *old object* to the *corresponding value* of the new-one and then **delete** the old-one from the list.

I've tried to add objects to a `Set` but even though `id`s are the same, their values are different, so it didn't work.

*My current code:*

```
while (true) {
  String input = scanner.nextLine();
  int id;
  int value1;
  int value2;
  int value3;
  int value4;
  List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
  SomeObject record = new SomeObject(id, value1, value2, value3, value4);
  list.add(record);

  for (SomeObject s : list) {
 
     if (s.getId() == id) {
        s.update1(value1);
        s.update2(value2);
        s.update3(value3);
        s.update4(value4);
        break;          
     }       
   }
  list.removeIf(n -> n.getId() == id);
}
```

`SomeObject` class:

```
public class SomeObject {
    private int id;
    private int value1;
    private int value2;
    private int value3;
    private int value4;
    
    // getters, constructor
    
    public int update1(int x) {
        return this.value1 = value1 + x;
    }
    
    public int update2(int x) {
        return this.value2 = value2 + x;
    }
    
    public int update3(int x) {
        return this.value3 = value3 + x;
    }
    
    public int update4(int x) {
        return this.value4 = value4 + x;
    }
}
```

*Input example:*

```
id=1243245 1 1 1 1 // old object

id=1243245 2 2 2 2 // new object
```

*Current output:*

```
id=1243245 2 2 2 2 // <- values of the new object
```

*Desired output:*

```
id=1243245 3 3 3 3 // <- combined
```

Comment: Yes i added it now, the main problem with this is that after 'removeIf' method i can't make use of "update' instance method and my new values are same as input

Comment: *"Each time i create a new object and it has same id as old"* - but in the loop you've modified the **existing** objects having the given `id`, so that's not what you want? So your intention is to grab their values, add them to the values of the new object and replace the previous objects with it? How many objects having the given `id` you expect to be present in the list, at most one (IDs are unique) ?

Comment: Added input and output

Comment: Please, clarify whether `id`s are unique and at most one instance having the given `id` is expected to be present in the list, or not?

Comment: Yes, i need only unique id's on list. I just tried out your code and unfortunately it still makes a new instance with the same id and I end up with 2 objects with same id and i need only one, maybe its a bug in my code so give me a moment

Comment: Your answer looks right so i am gonna work on it later, first i have to organize other functions coz its quite messy, maybe thats why it doesnt work, for now i have to go for few hours, thank you for help

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that there's at most one instance of `SomeObject` having the given `id` in the list, you can iterate until this object has been found (or until the list is fully discovered), and if the object with the target `id` exists update the *new objects* using properties of the old-one.

Then remove the old-one break, break the loop, and finally add the new object.

**Note:** to avoid iterating over the list **twice**, which would be the case if to remove the *old object* we would use methods `remove(Object)` or `removeIf(Predicate)` (like in the original code), we can use either:

- traditional index-based `for`-loop and `remove(int)`, which removes object by index (but still it might result in additional iteration if list implementation would be a `LinkedList` and not `ArrayList`);
- the second option would be to use `Iterator` and it's method `remove()`, which removes the element at the current position. For all implementation of the `List` (that support removal of elements) it would be done in a constant time **O(1)**.

That's how it can be implemented using iterator:

```
public static void replaceById(List<SomeObject> list,
                               int id, int value1, int value2, int value3, int value4) {
    
    SomeObject record = new SomeObject(id, value1, value2, value3, value4);
    Iterator<SomeObject> iter = list.iterator();
    
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        SomeObject next = iter.next();

        if (next.getId() == id) {
            record.update1(next.getValue1()); // updating new object
            record.update2(next.getValue2());
            record.update3(next.getValue3());
            record.update4(next.getValue4());

            iter.remove();                    // removing old object
            break;
        }
    }
    
    list.add(record); // adding new object to the list
}
```

**Sidenote:** in order to be able to use your objects in hash-based collections, you need the `equals/hashCode` contract to be properly overridden.